# How to create a command of ItemSource Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, command

I'm attempting to convert my application to a MVVM architechture but I've ran into a problem with the itemsource. There is no command property available.

How am I supposed to convert itemtapped and Menuitem clicked to MVVM commands? 
Currently using FRESHMVVM. I've found some solutions when googling but they seemed very complicated for this.

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <converters:StatusTextConverter x:Key="IntStatusToTextConverter" />
                <converters:DateTextConverter x:Key="DateToTextConverter" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ContentPage.Resources>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Issues}" ItemTapped="OnEventSelected" SeparatorColor="#444444" RowHeight="90" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}" RefreshCommand="{Binding PullRefreshCommand}" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell >
                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <MenuItem Clicked="OnDelete" Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />
                        </ViewCell.ContextActions>

                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding SeverityImagePath}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="70"/>
                                <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding StatusImagePath}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="60"/>

                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" YAlign="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Font="Bold, Medium"/>
                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Created, Converter={StaticResource DateToTextConverter}}" YAlign="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Font="Medium"/>
                                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" YAlign="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" Font="Small"/>
                            </Grid>

                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

PageModel Method

```
 public async void OnEventSelected(object o, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsBusy)
                return;


            var item = e.Item as IssueModel;
            if (item != null)
            {
                MessagingCenter.Subscribe<IssuePageModel>(this, "refresh", async (sender) =>
                {
                    MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<IssueListPageModel>(this, "refresh");
                    await OnRefreshContent();
                });

                IssuePageModel page = null;
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading event...", maskType: MaskType.Clear);

                    // Does lost of stuff, So show loading message

                    UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                });

                if (item != null)
                    await CoreMethods.PushPageModel<IssuePageModel>(item);
            }

        }


 public async void OnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var mi = ((MenuItem)sender);
            IssueModel issue = mi.BindingContext as IssueModel;
            if (issue != null)
            {
                IsBusy = true;

                bool bDeleted = await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        App.Client.DeleteIssue(issue.Id);
                        return Issues.Remove(issue);
                    }
                    catch (Exception /*ex*/)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                if (bDeleted == false)
                    await CoreMethods.DisplayAlert("Failed", "Failed to remove item", "Continue");

                IsBusy = false;

            }
        }
```

Comment: I would suggest using Event to Command Behavior. There's a good article on that here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior/

Comment: I understand a bit about it, but not sure how I would apply it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so first off, add the following two classes - shamelessly stolen from the example in my comment - to your project:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace EventToCommandBehavior
{
    public class BehaviorBase<T> : Behavior<T> where T : BindableObject
    {
        public T AssociatedObject { get; private set; }

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(T bindable)
        {
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
            AssociatedObject = bindable;

            if (bindable.BindingContext != null)
            {
                BindingContext = bindable.BindingContext;
            }

            bindable.BindingContextChanged += OnBindingContextChanged;
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(T bindable)
        {
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
            bindable.BindingContextChanged -= OnBindingContextChanged;
            AssociatedObject = null;
        }

        void OnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnBindingContextChanged();
        }

        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();
            BindingContext = AssociatedObject.BindingContext;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace EventToCommandBehavior
{
    public class EventToCommandBehavior : BehaviorBase<View>
    {
        Delegate eventHandler;

        public static readonly BindableProperty EventNameProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("EventName",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(EventToCommandBehavior),
                null,
                propertyChanged: OnEventNameChanged);

        public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("Command",
                typeof(ICommand),
                typeof(EventToCommandBehavior),
                null);

        public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("CommandParameter",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(EventToCommandBehavior),
                null);

        public static readonly BindableProperty InputConverterProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("Converter",
                typeof(IValueConverter),
                typeof(EventToCommandBehavior),
                null);

        public string EventName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(EventNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EventNameProperty, value); }
        }

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public object CommandParameter
        {
            get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
        }

        public IValueConverter Converter
        {
            get { return (IValueConverter)GetValue(InputConverterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InputConverterProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(View bindable)
        {
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
            RegisterEvent(EventName);
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(View bindable)
        {
            DeregisterEvent(EventName);
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        }

        void RegisterEvent(string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            {
                return;
            }

            EventInfo eventInfo = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent(name);
            if (eventInfo == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("EventToCommandBehavior: Can't register the '{0}' event.", EventName));
            }
            MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(EventToCommandBehavior).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("OnEvent");
            eventHandler = methodInfo.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this);
            eventInfo.AddEventHandler(AssociatedObject, eventHandler);
        }

        void DeregisterEvent(string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (eventHandler == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            EventInfo eventInfo = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent(name);
            if (eventInfo == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("EventToCommandBehavior: Can't de-register the '{0}' event.", EventName));
            }
            eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(AssociatedObject, eventHandler);
            eventHandler = null;
        }

        void OnEvent(object sender, object eventArgs)
        {
            if (Command == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            object resolvedParameter;
            if (CommandParameter != null)
            {
                resolvedParameter = CommandParameter;
            }
            else if (Converter != null)
            {
                resolvedParameter = Converter.Convert(eventArgs, typeof(object), null, null);
            }
            else
            {
                resolvedParameter = eventArgs;
            }

            if (Command.CanExecute(resolvedParameter))
            {
                Command.Execute(resolvedParameter);
            }
        }

        static void OnEventNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var behavior = (EventToCommandBehavior)bindable;
            if (behavior.AssociatedObject == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            string oldEventName = (string)oldValue;
            string newEventName = (string)newValue;

            behavior.DeregisterEvent(oldEventName);
            behavior.RegisterEvent(newEventName);
        }
    }
}
```

The EventToCommandBehavior class can be used to call a command from an event with any class that derives from `View`. You can attach it to your `ListView` like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:EventToCommandBehavior"
             x:Class="FormsBehaviors.Views.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <behaviors:SelectedItemEventArgsToSelectedItemConverter x:Key="SelectedItemConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Thingies}">
            <ListView.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemSelected" 
                                                  Command="{Binding FooCommand}" 
                                                  Converter="{StaticResource SelectedItemConverter}" />
            </ListView.Behaviors>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The converter is optional. If you omit it, your command will be called with the relevant event args. In this case it makes sense to use a converter to extract the selected item from the event args and pass that along as a command parameter. Here's the converter, for completeness:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace EventToCommandBehavior
{
    public class SelectedItemEventArgsToSelectedItemConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var eventArgs = value as SelectedItemChangedEventArgs;
            return eventArgs.SelectedItem;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Remember, the first two classes - `BehaviorBase` and `EventToCommandBehavior` are not exclusive to `ListView`, they can be used with any class that derives from `View`. Also, there is another property, `CommandParameter` that can be used to pass an explicit parameter to the command you're binding to, if you can't/don't want to use the event args. See the `OnEvent` Method of `EventToCommandBehavior` for further details.

**Edit:** 
Explanation of using Commands. Your ViewModel implementing the command should look something like this (not using a converter)

```
public class MainVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<Thingy> Thingies { get; set; }
    public ICommand FooCommand { get; set; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        Thingies = new ObservableCollection<Thingy>();
        FooCommand = new Command(Bar);
    }

    private void Bar(object eventArgs)
    {
        var args = eventArgs as SelectedItemChangedEventArgs;
        if (args == null)
            return;

        var selectedItem = args.SelectedItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might sound silly, but how will I consume the command? I tried this, but couldn't figure it out quite. 
"public ICommand OnSelectedIssueCommand
        {
            get { return OnEventSelected ?? new Command<object o, ItemTappedEventArgs e>(); }
        }

        public async void OnEventSelected(object o, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {"

Comment: Have you considered using an MVVM library, such as MVVMLight? That gives you a very nice implementation of ICommand (and saves you a LOT of work) Let me know if you want to go that way and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Absolutely, I use freshMVVM and still Learning all the things it can do. Learning pagemodel navigation took some time

Comment: OK, I haven't used that one. Give me some time to investigate.

Comment: Thanks man! Really appreciate this help. Never used commands Before MVVM and it was such a mess in the beginning. But hey, here I am. :)

Comment: Yeah, and the documentation is not great. If you have a Pluralsight subscription, I'd recommend looking into MVVMLight, which has a great course there.

Comment: Will check it out for the next Project for sure! I got an pluralsight subscription through my job so that's good. But how the hell am I supposed to use the command? My top-comment was my attempt but that was so far off. Can only find one sample by Xamarin team, but they send a Collection instead of the eventargs or something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166816/discussion-between-frauke-nonnenmacher-and-jsondork).